# What is the syntax for referring to named scopes within Squeel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, squeel

Is there a way, using Squeel, to refer to already existing scopes?

Consider the following:

```
scope :continuous, where{ job_type_id == 1 }
scope :standard, where{ job_type_id == 2 }

scope :active, where{ (job_status_id == 2) & ((job_type_id == 1) | ((job_type_id == 2) & (date_start > Time.now) & (date_end < Time.now))) }
```

All three scopes work properly, but the logic from the first two (`continuous` and `standard`) are duplicated within the third, which is what I'd like to avoid, by doing something like:

```
scope :active, where{ (job_status_id == 2) & (continuous | (standard & (date_start > Time.now) & (date_end < Time.now))) }
```

... except that I can't find the correct syntax in the Squeel DSL for referring to named scopes.

Is there a way to do what I'd like, or do I just need to be explicit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squeel currently doesn't support referencing named scopes. The preferred method is using Squeel sifters and then using the sifters in your scopes:

```
sifter :continuous { where{ job_type_id == 1 }}
sifter :standard   { where{ job_type_id == 2 }}

scope :continuous, -> { where{ sift(:continuous) }}
scope :standard,   -> { where{ sift(:standard) }}
scope :active,     -> { where{ (job_status_id == 2) & (sift(:continuous) | (sift(:standard) & (date_start > Time.now) & (date_end < Time.now)) }}
```

Clearly still some repetition, and probably not the best example or use, but just wanted to show how to implement your example with them.

Reference sifters: https://github.com/ernie/squeel#sifters